# rails + passenger + devise - wrong url redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, passenger

When I hit the a production url `https://studio.myapp.biz`, then it redirects to  `https://studio.myapp.bizusers/sign_in`. Notice that it doesn't add `/` after the domain. This issue occurs with all omniauth callback urls as well.

The application runs on on Apache 2 + Passenger 5.0.25.

**Apache**

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/rubyapps/studio_server/current/public
    ServerName studio.myapp.biz
    PassengerRuby /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/wrappers/ruby
    RailsEnv production
    <Directory /var/www/rubyapps/studio_server/current/public>
        allow from all
        Require all granted
        AllowOverride All
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**routes.rb**

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {
    registrations: 'registrations',
    invitations: 'users/invitations',
    omniauth_callbacks: "users/omniauth_callbacks",
}
```

I am not able to figure out where the issue is. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a missing trailing slash in the Apache redirection statement in the :80 setup redirecting to SSL:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
  ServerName studio.myapp.biz
  Redirect permanent / https://studio.myapp.biz/
  <Directory /var/www/html>
    allow from all
    Require all granted
    AllowOverride All
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

This looks surprising though that we have to explicitly specify `/` in redirection statement.